# How to use while loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**js code**

```js
var links2 = {
  setColor2: function(color) {
    var alist = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var i = 0;
    while (i < alist.length) {
      alist[i].style.color = color;
      i += 1; 
    }
  }
}
```

how can i perform loop in jquery just like this?

Comment: [`.css`](//api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: jquery each https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: @HosMercury What does ajax you linked to have to do with any of this?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't require the loop at all to set all `a` elements `style` property. You use [`css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
var links2 = {
  setColor2: function(color) {
    $('a').css("color",color)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to give a value only to a specific a element . Is there no way?

Comment: @김혜진 Sure you can but that's not what you asked in the question and nothing in the loop in the question would indicate how you want to target a specific element. You are welcome to ask another question with more specific criteria but this answer does what you asked for and changing the scope after answers are submitted is not productive

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for letting me know. And I'm sorry. It was only after the other people's answers that I found my question inaccurate. I'll be careful next time. Thank you for your advice. \(￣︶￣*\))

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
$("a").each(function (){
  $(this).css("color", "red")
})
```

As pointed out .each is redundant, and if you don't need the loop you can do:

```
$("a").css("color", "red")
```

Comment: Theres no need for the loop at all

Comment: The `each` is redundant...`$('a').css()` will do an each  loop internally

Comment: Just edited, it should be "a" as in your example.